# How to extract compilation args for each compilation unit in a vcxproj?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, clang, visual-studio-sdk

I'm trying to get the compilation args for each compilation unit so I can create the "[compilation_commands.json](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html)" for my vcxproj that can be used with clang's libTooling.

The [libTooling tutorial](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html) suggests using a `CompilationDatabase` to provide the compilation args for all the cpp files in a project. The tutorial shows that CMake can generate the compilation_commands.json for CMake based projects.

Since clang can be put into "MSVC mode" via `clang.exe --driver-mode=cl` or `clang-cl.exe` my thought was if I could get the compilation args for each cpp file in my VS2012 project I can create the compilation_commands.json for a vcxproj.

However I'm having trouble finding APIs in the VS2012 SDK that walks a vcxproj and retrieves the compilation args for each compilation unit. Can someone point me towards the right APIs?

Comment: You are not going to find this in the Visual Studio SDK, building is the job of MSBuild.exe.  You can tinker with the .targets files but high odds you'll get lost quickly.  The very simple approach is to provide substitutes for cl.exe and link.exe.  That capture the command line and write it to a file.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is really old, but the question is still relevant, so for those still looking for an answer, I managed to finally do this recently using [this](https://github.com/CoatiSoftware/vs-sourcetrail) little VS extension.

Just install it and a new 'Sourcetrail' menu will appear, with a 'Create Compilation Database' entry (I found Intellisense needs to be enabled for it to be clickable). That will let you customize what to include and generate a `compile_commands.json` that you can use with other clang-based tools, etc.

Comment: I am so happy you posted this! Helped me alot! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is a DIY job. The VS IDE projects have properties for each .cpp file. By selecting a .cpp, then right-click -> Properties -> Config properties -> C/C++ -> Command-Line you have the options required to compile that specific file. The 64 dollar question is how to do it for every file in the project  / solution. The answer is not trivial, but it is doable. At least I did it on VS 2010 and I'm pretty sure it works on VS 2012/3

The secret lies with what is called VCEngine. It is a tool that evaluates all the properties or the files in the project. So the real problem is how to evaluate the property "Command Line" for each file. You need to iterate through all the .cpp files and call VCProject's Evaluate method for the "Command Line" property.

The simplest way I think you can do it is to write a plugin for the VS IDE and thus gain access to the VCEngine instance. There are plenty of examples of how to do that. Be aware that the VCEngine is version dependent.

Anywhay, for projects/solutions with thousands of .cpp files, you need to automate the compilation database creation.

When I'll have time I will put the solution on github

Answer (score 1):

You can try to parse the CL.command.* files in the intermediate directories.

https://gist.github.com/Trass3r/f3fbe6807d28106e917368c33abf45d4

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in reading this
[compile_commands.json for Windows/MSVC](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/compile-commands-json-for-Windows-MSVC-td4033848.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by hijacking the compiler. The main downside is that you will no longer receive the name of the compiler binary.

1. Embed this Python script in a `cc.bat` (which also converts `INCLUDE=...` environment variables to [`/external:I...` parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/external-external-headers-diagnostics)):
   `@python3 -u -s -E -I -c "import io, json, os, subprocess, sys; argv = sys.argv[1:]; cc = 'cl.exe'; includes = ['/external:I' + s for s in os.getenv('INCLUDE', '').split(os.pathsep) if s]; is_resp = len(argv) > 0 and argv[0].startswith('@'); cmdline = io.open(argv[0][1:], 'r', encoding='utf-16-le').read().lstrip('\uFEFF') if is_resp else None; filename = (cmdline[cmdline.rfind('\x22', 0, len(cmdline) - 2):].strip('\x22') if cmdline.rstrip().endswith('\x22') else cmdline[cmdline.rfind(' ') + 1:]) if is_resp else argv[-1]; json.dump({'directory': os.getcwd(), 'file': filename, ('command' if is_resp else 'arguments'): subprocess.list2cmdline([cc]) + ' ' + cmdline + (' ' + subprocess.list2cmdline(includes) if includes else '') if is_resp else [cc] + argv + includes}, sys.stdout)" %*`
2. Then call MSBuild with `MultiProcCL` set to `true` (this is important because otherwise you'll receive multiple file names in the same compile command):
   `MSBuild -noLogo -v:m -t:ClCompile -p:BuildInParallel=false -m:1 -p:MultiProcMaxCount=1 -p:MultiProcCL=true -p:CLToolExe="%CD%\cc.bat"`
   I'm not sure if the `-p:MultiProcMaxCount=1` is strictly necessary to avoid line interleaving; you may be able to take it out.

You now have a bunch of JSON lines on stdout, one for each file, which you can manually join using commas (and embed inside brackets) to create a JSON array.