# use clang to produce AST of C++/MFC code?

Tags: clang, llvm

I tested LLVM compiler tool chain and builds a generic MFC application using LLVM-VS2010 as platform toolset from .vcproj.  But what I need is just the Abstract Syntax Tree dump.  I tried clang-check but shows the ff:

LLVM ERROR: Could not detect compilation database...json-compilation-database: Error while opening JSON database: no such file or directory.

Found out that json compilation database is generated by cmake (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html).

Is there a way to skip compilation database and just produce ast-dump?

Comment: I don't think there is any easy way to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672867/how-to-extract-compilation-args-for-each-compilation-unit-in-a-vcxproj

Comment: yeah, looks like it is.  Just need to wait for future fix. thanks!